# How to tell the heat, or at least fan speed, of a machine

Tags: overheating, fan

Is there a way in which I can tell how hot my computer is? Or at least how fast my computer's fan is going? Because if my computer's fan knows how fast and when to go, then surely my computer knows the heat of my computer?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```